# Is it a acceptable to hide a property in a derived interface which returns a derived type?

Tags: c#, interface, covariance, method-hiding

## TL;DR

**What is wrong with hiding a property in an interface so that I can change its declaration to return a derived type of the original property?**

I'm sure this must have been asked before, but I can't find it, and apologies for the long question.

Say I have this situation:

```
public interface A
{
    B TheB{get;}
}

public interface MoreSpecificA : A
{
    MoreSpecificB TheMoreSpecificB{get;}
}

public interface B{...}

public interface MoreSpecificB:B{...}
```

I would like users of `MoreSpecificA` to be able to get at the B which is a `MoreSpecificB`.  They could do this by calling `TheB` and cast it, or they could call the method `TheMoreSpecificB`.  I could also declare `MoreSpecificA` like so:

```
public interface MoreSpecificA : A
{
    new MoreSpecificB TheB{get;}
}
```

so that now they can just use the same method and get back a `MoreSpecificB`.

Using the `new` to hide a method puts my teeth on edge, so why is this a bad idea?  It seems like a reasonable thing to do here.

The general suggestion in most cases I have seen for this seems to be to use generics instead, but this seems to have a problem in that if I have a `MoreSpecificA` and I want to return it in a method that declares the return type as `A` then I have to have `MoreSpecificA` extend `A` which gives ambiguity when accessing `TheB` on the `MoreSpecificA` instance as it doesn't know if you want `A.TheB` or `MoreSpecificA.TheB`

```
public interface ABase<T> where T : B
{
    T TheB{get;}
}

public interface A : ABase<B>
{        
}

public interface MoreSpecificA : ABase<MoreSpecificB>,A
{        
}

public class blah
{
    public A GetA(MoreSpecificA specificA)
    {
        return specificA; //can't do this unless MoreSpecificA extends A 
    }

    public B GetB(MoreSpecificA specificA)
    {
        return specificA.TheB; //compiler complains about ambiguity here, if MoreSpcificA extends A
    }
}
```

which could be solved by declaring a new TheB on MoreSpecificA (but the new issue again).

If MoreSpecificA doesn't extend A then the first method in the class `blah` above complains as now as  MoreSpcificA can't be converted to A.

Whilst writing this I have noticed that if I declare my BaseA to be contravariant like this:

```
public interface ABase<out T> where T : B
{
    T TheB{get;}
}
```

and my class to be

```
public class blah
{
    public ABase<B> GetA(MoreSpecificA specificA)
    {
        return specificA; 
    }

    public B GetB(MoreSpecificA specificA)
    {
        return specificA.TheB; //compiler complains about ambiguity here
    }
}
```

Then I get the best of both worlds.  Does the applicability of this solution depend on whether `A` adds anything to `ABase`?

Or is my original plan of just hiding the method in the derived type to return a derived type of the original method ok?

Comment: They way I see it you're just running into one of the limitations not having multiple inheritance creates. Maybe some factory or builder pattern can save the day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Or is my original plan of just hiding the method in the derived type to return a derived type of the original method ok?

So long as it means *exactly the same thing*, I think it's okay. You can see something like this in the standard libraries, with [`IDbConnection.CreateCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idbconnection.createcommand.aspx) (which returns `IDbCommand`) and [`SqlConnection.CreateCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.createcommand.aspx) (which returns `SqlCommand`) for example.

In that case it's using explicit interface implementation for the `IDbConnection` version, but it's the same principle.

You can also see it in `IEnumerator<T>.Current` vs `IEnumerator.Current` and `IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()` vs `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()`.

I would only use it in cases where the implementation for the more weakly-typed method *just* returns the result of calling the more strongly-typed method though, use implicit conversion. When they actually start doing different things, that becomes much harder to reason about later.

Comment: Thanks Jon.  In my case the object in question is used as a Key.  In the system all keys implement `IKey` with some more specific keys interfaces which are used as markers for keys for classes of types.  In all implementation classes they have a single Key of a concrete type and all implementations of interface methods which return an IKey (or a derivation of) will return the same instance.

Comment: @SamHolder: Sounds okay then. Basically this is making up for the lack of covariant return types in .NET :(